# How to get Custom HTTP header in Magento2 controller?

Tags: magento2, php, api, rest-api, postman

[image]I'm accessing my controller via postman tool ([Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en))

I've passed custom header as shown in image and trying to access it in controller through this code:

```
$this->_response->getHeader('APP_ID');
```

but it returns no data. Please Help.

Answer (score 2):

Finally, got the solution

```
$httpRequestObject = new \Zend_Controller_Request_Http();
$httpRequestObject->getHeader('APP_ID');
```

Thank you!

Comment: I am using POSTMAN for rest api, How can i get my oAuth 2 details, now i have all my oAuth 1 details as well as working, now we decide to move oAuh 2, so that how can i  get my oAuth 2 details? @ Manish Joy

Comment: Hello, i have same requirement please share full code

Comment: @devhs please check the solutions given below. Its explained there.

Answer (score 2):

As long as your controller is a child of AbstractAction you can also access this data by request instance: `$this->getRequest()->getHeader('APP_ID')`

Comment: I'm not sure why this was initially downvoted, as this worked perfectly for me! There may be situations where `$this->getRequest()` isn't available, so include the class `\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface` in your constructor, as explained here: https://mage2.pro/t/topic/235

Answer (score 0):

Remember that [All caps HTTP headers with underscores dropped in Apache 2.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440564/all-caps-http-headers-with-underscores-dropped-in-apache-2-4).

Nginx:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers

So we can try add other values. For example: `AppId` without underscores.

We could get the header with

```
\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface

\Magento\Framework\Webapi\Request

\Magento\Framework\HTTP\PhpEnvironment\Request
```